# How can I use a Python script to add a specified file to Metashape chunks?

Tags: python, typescript

want to automatically add a specified file using a script in Metashape program, but it's not appearing in the chunks. What should I do?

```
import Metashape
import os

doc = Metashape.Document()
photo_folder = os.path.expanduser("~/Desktop/dronepics")
chunk = doc.addChunk()

for filename in os.listdir(photo_folder):
    if filename.endswith(".jpg") or filename.endswith(".jpeg"):
        photo_path = os.path.join(photo_folder, filename)
        photo = Metashape.Photo()
        photo.open(photo_path)
        chunk.addPhotos([photo])
doc.save(os.path.expanduser("~/Desktop/çıktı/proje.psx"))
```

The code I have written, where did I make a mistake and can you tell me the correct version?

Comment: Why is this tagged as typescript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See how it is done in official GitHub script:
https://github.com/agisoft-llc/metashape-scripts/blob/master/src/samples/general_workflow.py

```
    import os, Metashape
    def find_files(folder, types):
        return [entry.path for entry in os.scandir(folder) if (entry.is_file() and os.path.splitext(entry.name)[1].lower() in types)]
    doc = Metashape.Document() 
    doc.save(output_folder + '/project.psx')
    chunk = doc.addChunk() 
    photos = find_files(image_folder, [".jpg", ".jpeg", ".tif", ".tiff"])
    chunk.addPhotos(photos) 
    doc.save()
```